# Is it possible to reduce the memory allocated by Google Chrome for my web page?

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome, memory-management

I am trying to make a website with a minimalist feeling to it, so I put a fullscreen image on the background as `background-image` of `body`. I have a `transition: background-position 1s` set as a CSS rule for `body` and an easing function, to create a smooth scrolling effect when going to other pages in the same HTML file (I have no actual scrollbar, just navigation elements). The thing I noticed was that once I started scrolling, the memory reserved by the page went from a small 77MB to over 500MB! I tested this in Firefox, but it doesn't seem to happen (either because pages have no separate processes or memory allocation works differently, I imagine). Why does this happen in Google Chrome and not in other browsers? And how can I reduce the enormous amounts of memory reserved by my page?

To give some information on what I am using:

- Browser: Google Chrome
- RAM: 8GB The page uses javascript with the
  following plugins:

  - jQuery
  - Bootstrap
- Background image dimensions are: 1440 x 540

A few possible causes of the problem:

- The image is too big to be rendered with a `transition` and an easing function.
- I should not use `background-image` for this, but create a new `<img/>` as a background.
- I somehow only checked it with developer tools open in Chrome, increasing the memory allocated.
- It's not the image causing the problem, but the web fonts I scroll simultaneously with the background image, also using transition and an easing function.

And I want to add that maybe this is not even a problem after all, it's just that I have never seen a page go over 300MB with memory allocation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if this should be posted as a comment instead, however:

Nothing you can do about that. Chrome trades RAM for performance.
For instance each chrome tab runs on its own process for that purpose.

I had cases when a single youtube tab took over 1.5gb memory & virtual memory.
Even a blank tab takes 45mb memory for me.

So there is no issue with your code at all.

Comment: My youtube tabs only take about 150MB of my RAM, even though I'd expect it to be a lot more intensive performance-wise.